# Issue with arrays and output

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, call

I have a piece of code that will derive a random array and then do various computations within the method. The array will return to memory and then in the main method I have to write a test case to show how the methods work. I do not understand how to write the test case. 
   The array is a random array designed to have 10 random numbers between 1 and 999 and the following methods will double every other compute the mean and compute the range. 
           I have the following code and it won't compile due to errors in the main method. How can I fix it?

```
//main method test class
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.prntln(displayArr);
            System.out.println(findMean);
            System.out.pritnln(findRange);
            System.out.println(doubleEveryOther);
    }
    //first method
    public static void displayArr(int [] arr) {
        //loop to generate 10 random numbers 
         for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        double math = 1+ (int) Math.random() *999;
    }
         //create an array of 10 generated random numbers
        int [] math = new int [10];
        System.out.println(math);
    }

    //second method
    public static double findMean (int[] arr, int [] math) {
        // begin sum 
        int sum =0;
        //sum the values of the array 
        for (int i=0; i<math.length; i++) {
         sum = 0+math[i];
         //compute average 
        }
        double avg = sum/math.length;

        return avg;
    }
    //third method
        public static int findRange (int[] arr,int [] math) {
        //find the max
        int max =math[0];
        for (int i=1; i<math.length; i++) {
            if(math[i] >max) {
                max=math[i];
            }
        }
            // find the min. 
            int min = math[0];
            for(int j=1; j<math.length; j++) {
                if(math[j]<min) {
                    min = math[j];
                }

        }
        //max-min =range
                int range = max-min;
        return range;
    }
    //final method
    public static void doubleEveryOtherVal(int[] arr,int [] math) {
    //create a loop that only iterates for every other value 
    for (int i=1; i<math.length; i+=2){ 
    //extract every other value from the array 
    double odd = math[i]; 
    //compute 
            double twice = 2 *odd; 
    }   

    }
```

Comment: What are you asking? Why your code wont compile? How to write a test? How to write a test for random data?

Comment: I see a `prntln`instead of `println` in the third line.

Check the compiler output, it should tell you where the mistake is.
Also the line
    `sum = 0+math[i];` 
is supposed to say `sum = sum+math[i];` I assume

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Random generated array\n-----------------------");
        int[] test = displayArr();

        double avg = findMean(test);
        System.out.println("\nAverage " + avg);

        int range = findRange(test);
        System.out.println("Range " + range);

        System.out.println(
        "\nRandom generated array every value multiplied by 2 \n-----------------------------------------------------");
        doubleEveryOtherVal(test);


    }

    // first method
    public static int[] displayArr() {
        // loop to generate 10 random numbers
        int[] test = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Randomly generated doubles
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 10);
            test[i] = random;
        }

        // outputs the randomly generated numbers
        for (int d : test) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }

        // returns the array
        return test;
    }

    // second method
    public static double findMean(int[] arr) {
        // begin sum
        int sum = 0;
        // sum the values of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
            // compute average
        }

        double avg = sum / arr.length;

        return avg;
    }

    // third method
    public static int findRange(int[] arr) {
        int range = 0;

        // find max
        int max = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }

        // find the min.
        int min = arr[0];

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            if (arr[x] < min) {
                min = arr[x];
            }

        }

        // max-min =range
        range = max - min;

        return range;
    }

    // final method
    public static void doubleEveryOtherVal(int[] arr) {
        // create a loop that only iterates for every other value
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // extract every other value from the array
            arr[i] = arr[i] * 2;
        }

        for(int doubled : arr)
        {
            System.out.println(doubled);
        }

    }
}
```

There were many mistakes in the code that you were using. First of I don't know why you were using the second parameter in the methods called math. Another issue is that you cannot call a System.out.println() on a method which returns void.

I would also recommend that you use double for both the array and any place where you have an int to have a more precise value.

The final method is something which I could not understand well but I thought that you meant that it should double each value found in the array (Another reason why you should have used double throughout to have more precise values).

This is how you do a simple test using Junit testing.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestHello {

    @Test
    public void testAssertions() {
        Hello h1 = new Hello();

        // testing that the array returned has a length of 10
        assertTrue(h1.displayArr().length == 10);
    }

}
```

For more information about JUnit testing visit this link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_test_framework.htm

Hope you you find this well.